# Properties of the Git branch

Tags: git

Looking in the Git documentation it seems that branch:

- Has name
- Points at some commit

And there are no any other properties. Ex Git does not know the date when the branch was created. So, there is really nothing besides the two points listed above.

Is that true, or am I missing something?

Comment: A branch is a file which contains a commit reference. You could try and get that information from the file info.

Comment: You might be able to infer the approximate time of branching from date stamps of subsequent commits and the one just before the branch point, if that's what you're trying to ask. As long as you have a copy of the working directory, metadata in the `.git` directory in the file system may allow you to recover the exact timestamp.

Comment: For the most part, just think of the branch as a pointer to a commit.  There is also some associated meta data (remote, merge strategy, etc.)Look in `.git/config`

Comment: Although Git doesn't track when a branch was created, your Git repo hosting platform (i.e. GitHub, GitLab, Azure Repos, etc) may. Is this purely an academic question or is there some objective you'd like to accomplish with this information, if it were to exist?

Comment: You're missing the main thing that distinguishes a branch from a tag; if you check out a branch, then creating a commit *advances* the branch head automatically.

Comment: It's not only true, it's *intentionally* true: a branch name is not intended to "mean" anything in Git. Git does not care about branch names; it provides them so that humans can find commits that humans declare to be important because the human says that this is the latest commit for that branch. That is, the *name* doesn't matter: it is the *commit* that matters.

Comment: Yes, that's what  a ref name is: a name in a particular repo that currently refers to a particular commit in that repo. If you're looking to tie a commit to some external administrative record, put a marker in the commit message. Otherwise, what are you looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true; you aren't missing anything.

That being said, there are ways to find out more information about a branch, using other mechanisms. For example, suppose I create a branch called `develop-test` from the latest `develop` like this:

```
$ git branch develop-test origin/develop
Branch 'develop-test' set up to track remote branch 'develop' from 'origin'.
```

**(Possibly Useless...) Look at the date of the file pointer:**

```
# look at the file containing the branch (*nix shells)
$ ls -l .git/refs/heads/develop-test
-rw-r--r-- 1 TTT 1049089 41 May 27 13:44 .git/refs/heads/develop-test
```

<strike>This will show you the date that file was *created on your machine*.</strike> (Actually it should have said *modified* and you probably needed to use `stat` instead.) **Update:** unfortunately this is not very helpful. (TIL with minimal testing) Apparently Git re-writes the branch file at every change, so the modification and creation date are re-written together. This will not show you when the branch was actually created unless you didn't touch the branch since then.

Which leaves us with perhaps the best way:

**Look at the date of the reflog entry:**

If you've done something with the branch locally, e.g. perhaps you created it or checked it out, then you could look at the `reflog` for it and specify the datetime option:

```
$ git reflog develop-test --date=iso
4cb68e344af (origin/develop, origin/HEAD, develop-test) develop-test@{2022-05-27 13:44:27 -0500}: branch: Created from origin/develop
```